# Ultra customisation of an MSI file from TeamViewer

Tags: windows-installer, teamviewer

Ive got a little problem with an MSI file from TeamViewer. They add some "tab" as you can see here in the picture:
[image]

*réalité augmentée* or *plus de solution* and there is ads popping up on the screen ! I know we need to pay to remove the ads, but how custom the tab on the left ?Maybe some configuration file in the MSI I've missed ?
Thank you.

Comment: Which MSI file? Where do you get this context menu?

Comment: the msi file genrated by the console management, and i get this content on the client when i start it

Comment: This doesn't help.